# Windows 7-like Loading Animation

Tags: flash, animated-gif, pageload

I want a simple loading bar to display while I am loading an html web page. I want something similar to the look and feel of the animation that shows while windows in preparing to copy files (before it starts the percentage loader).

[image: Windows 7 Loader]

Can't use an animated gif, cause gifs freeze when the browser is overloaded. However, if anyone knows of a gif similar to the loader above, I will be willing to look at it. I have already made a javascript loading animation, but when other large scripts are running, the animation freezes.

This is why I would like to find one in flash. I am not a flash programmer, I code javascript. I just need a simple repeating flash loading animation similar to the one shown. I do not want a percentage to be shown. I have googled it for quite sometime now with no luck.

The answer with the best flash loading animation will be the solution.
Thanks for your help. I am still googling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you care so much for the vista loader....I have edited ur image itself into a flash animation. Used no codes, as you do not prefer them. Modify it as you like. 

Preview:
http://megaswf.com/simple_serve/80514/

Dowloadable fla (flash cs4): http://www.mediafire.com/?c8ucvce0473u99i

Hope that helps.

---

Edit:

I have tinkered that (left to right animation) bit for you. Here is the preview.

Preview : http://megaswf.com/simple_serve/80834/

Downloadable SWF (as you preferred) : http://www.mediafire.com/?5xha4a9j6hj7sal

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was hoping for one that went off the right side then started back at the left, instead of back and forth. But I appreciate it a lot! Also, is there a downloadable swf? I don't have anything to compile fla.